# ASP.net Core API error by implementing JWT in the configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, jwt

I recently added to my code the JWT method for authenticating users, after implementing all the configuration I am facing Exception at the CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run() in the program file.
The error I am facing:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Dmail.Core.Application.Login.LoginBL Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Dmail.Core.Application.Login.LoginBL': Unable to activate type 'Dmail.Core.Application.Login.LoginBL'. The following constructors are ambiguous:
>   Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration)
>   Void .ctor(Dmail.Core.Contracts.IUserRepository))'

This is my configuration for login authentication:

```
            services.AddCors(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => 
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials().Build());
        });

        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt: Issuer"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
            };
        });

        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddMvcOptions(o =>
        {
            o.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
        });

        services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<LoginBL, LoginBL>();
        services.AddTransient<GetUserBL, GetUserBL>();
        services.AddTransient<UserPresenter, UserPresenter>();
```

The class LoginBL:

```
public class LoginBL
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public LoginBL(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public LoginBL(IUserRepository userRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public async Task<LoginResponse> HandleAuthentication(LoginRequest input)
    {
        var auth = await _userRepo.Authenticate(input.Email, input.Password);

        if (auth == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var tokenStr = GenerateJSONWebToken(auth);

            var output = new LoginResponse()
            {
                Id = auth.Id,
                Username = auth.Username,
                FirstName = auth.FirstName,
                LastName = auth.LastName,
                Token = tokenStr,
                ListOfEmails = auth.ListOfEmails
            };

            return output;
        }
    }

    private string GenerateJSONWebToken(User userinfo)
    {
        var securityKey = new 
   SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, 
     SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, userinfo.FirstName),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, userinfo.Username),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
        };

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            audience: _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(120),
            signingCredentials: credentials);

        var encodetoken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return encodetoken;

    }
}
```

If you need me to show you more files let me know, since I have quite a lot of files in my project

Comment: LoginBL has two different constructors which accept different arguments. Why? Can you supply the code for `LoginBL`? Also, you'll probably have trouble with this line: `Configuration["Jwt: Issuer"]` because of the space.

Comment: Added to the question

Comment: Is there a reason why `LoginBL` has two constructors, one accepting `IConfiguration ` and one accepting `IUserRepository`? Which one do you want to use?

Comment: The eagle eye, thanks a lot for noticing my stupid mistake!!!
I fixed it immediately and didn't recieve error afterward.
@John thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different constructors, so the container doesn't know which one to instantiate:

```
public LoginBL(IConfiguration config)
{
    _config = config;
}
public LoginBL(IUserRepository userRepo)
{
    _userRepo = userRepo;
}
```

Presumably you want a single constructor that takes both:

```
public LoginBL(IConfiguration config, IUserRepository userRepo)
{
    _config = config;
    _userRepo = userRepo;
}
```